# Персонаж должен тащить обьект

Tags: c#, .net, unity3d

подскажите как это реализовать:Персонаж должен тащить объект.В инете искал ничего не нашел.

Comment: Так опиши как ты пытаешься это сделать, пример кода, вряд ли кто-то за тебя будет писать классы и методы.

Comment: тащить обьект -- понятие очень растяжимое. Можно, скажем, ухватится за ящик и тащить его по полу. Можно поднять ящик и переносить его в руках, и для многих это будет тоже "тащить". Опиши как можно детальнее что ты хочешь получить и что ты уже пробовал сделать.

Comment: я ничего не пробовал т к просто не знаю как это реализовать вы просто подскажите а я сам код напишу .обьект должен тащиться по полу .

Comment: @Andrew выше !!!

Comment: не вижу ничего выше. Еще раз перечитай мой вопрос. Как именно ты хочешь таскать?

Comment: @Andrew говорю обьект должен тащиться по полу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таскать один обьект за другим обьектом можно через Joint. У документации юнити видеотуториал по использованию джоинтов.

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/physics-joints

А вот здесь можно найти подобный туториал, только для создания физики таскания на веревке при помощи джоинтов:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4YCj4Tid0w

уже не официальный.

Comment: спасибо !!!!!!!!!